# pandas to_csv not working with html in dataframe

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, character-encoding, export-to-csv

I scraped a site and stored the source code from various endpoints in a dataframe with 2 columns, the url and the source code.

When trying to export this dataframe using the to_csv method, I can't get the output file to open correctly in excel. This has something to do with using the correct encoding or delimiter, but I'm not sure how to choose the one that will make the output csv match the dataframe.

I'm guessing the problem is that commas, spaces, newline, newtab etc. characters all appear in the html so the to_csv method is struggling to determine which are genuine delimiters and which are just part of the html. I have no idea how to fix this though, any ideas?

Comment: What does the output look like when you open it with a text editor?

Comment: @sekky Pretty much how I would expect, it looks like the info in the dataframe separated by commas. That being said maybe my problem is something that can be solved in excel, rather than by changing the parameters of the to_csv method?

Comment: Okay. And what do you mean when you say you "can't get the output file to open correctly in excel"? Does it display some error message or display that data the wrong way?